# <li> items to go to next line if length of <ul> exceeds screen width

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, html-lists

I have a list [(click for fiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/v8etujog/):

```
  <ul class="list-items" :style="styleObject">
    <li v-for="(item, index) in listItems" :key="index">
      <span v-if="index != 0">, </span><span>{{ item.name }}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.list-items {
  display: inline-flex;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
</style>
```

and it looks like this:

[image]

which is great on desktop, but when the screen get smaller, words get scrambled instead of going to the next line:

[image]

What I want is that whenever the last word exceeds the width of the screen it goes to the next line so my list doesn't get scrambled like the above picture, how can I do that?

**NOTE**
Not sure if it's important or not but `class="list-items"` is in a div with the following style:

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;`
```

Comment: Are you looking for `display: inline-block`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add "flex-wrap:wrap;" to the rule like this:

```
.list-items {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Comment: **Caveat:** Since you did not account for the commas, they become "hanging" commas on the next line.

Answer (score 1):

I would improve this by doing the following:

1. Add wrap the `.list-items`
2. Add a class to the delimiter i.e. `,` (comma) e.g. `.delim`
3. Move the delimiter end; so that comma that follows the word instead of wrapping to the next line.
4. Make sure the `<span>` elements within the `<li>` to not wrap by disabling wrapping.
5. Remove the left padding from the `<ul>`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    listItems: [
      { name: "Mystery"},
      { name: "Western" },
      { name: "Drama"},
      { name: "Action" },
      { name: "Romance" },
      { name: "Kids" },
      { name: "Film Noir" },
      { name: "Biographical" },
    ]
  }
})
```

```css
#app {
  border: thin dashed red;
  max-width: 14em;
}

ul.list-items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

ul.list-items li {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

ul.list-items li span.delim {
  margin-right: 0.25em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
 <ul class="list-items" :style="styleObject">
    <li v-for="(item, index) in listItems" :key="index">
      <span>{{ item.name }}</span><span class="delim" v-if="index < listItems.length - 1">,</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is an external Fiddle as well: https://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/73rgd82a/